# passport.use is not a function typeerror

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add passport service to my app , but I am getting the following error, I have already installed all the dependencies and tried searching for this error but got none , please Help

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
^

TypeError: passport.use is not a function
at Object. (D:\My Data\Works\React\Google authentication\auth.js:6:10)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object. (D:\My Data\Works\React\Google authentication\index.js:6:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)

Node.js v18.16.1

My auth.js here

```
const passport = require("passport-google-oauth2");
const GoogleStrategy = require( 'passport-google-oauth2' ).Strategy;

require('dotenv').config()

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:     process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback   : true
  },
function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        done(null,profile);
      }
));

passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
    done(null,profile)
});

passport.deserializeUser((user,done)=>{
    done(null,user);
})
```

my index.js here

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport-google-oauth2');
const session = require('express-session')
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
require('./auth');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'client')));

function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
    req.user ? next() : res.sendStatus(401)
}

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(index.html);
});

//IMPORTANT TO SET COOCKIES

app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
  }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//TILL HERE

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope:
      [ 'email', 'profile' ] }
));

app.get( '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate( 'google', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/google/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/google/failure'
}));

app.get('/auth/google/failure',isLoggedIn,(req,res) => {
    res.send("Something went wrong");
});

app.get('/auth/protected',isLoggedIn,(req,res) => {
    let name = req.user.displayName;
    res.send(`Hello ${name}`);
});

app.use('/auth/logout',(req,res) => {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.send('see you again');
})

app.listen(5000,() => {
    console.log('listening on port 5000');
});
```

Comment: `const passport = require('passport-google-oauth2')` This does not make sense, you need to install `passport` and require this module: `const passport = require('passport')`

Comment: Voting to close as a typo (since you are trying to require `passport-google-oauth2` twice instead of `passport-google-oauth2` once and `passport` once).

Comment: was helpful .Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try to import `passport` like this:

```
const passport = require("passport-google-oauth2").Strategy;
```

And you can use it like this:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:     GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://yourdomain:3000/auth/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

I got it from the [official docs](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth2/)